# Get http requests in web browser

Tags: .net, wpf, get, browser, httprequest

I am using WPF WebBrowser control. How can I detect all outgoing Http GET requests that are executed on the pages? Basically I want something similar to the "network" tab in Chrome's Developer tools... is there something like "RequestBegins" event?

Comment: Do you want to detect all get requests from the current PC, current browser(hosting the WPF app), or only the session that the WPF app is running in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can get all requests but you can get iframe src requests ( navigating event will fire on iframes and frames) To get all requests you need proxy intercepts like Mu Mind  said Fiddler is great for that and it has DLL and easy API so you can embed it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Fiddler HTTP debugging proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It might help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks. but I want to do it in my own app, not using Fiddler.